# How to disable direct access from URL

Tags: angular

I signed in as user ('X') that having an ID == 1 . When i try to access to update my profile on this link //localhost:4200/my-account/1 it works all fine but when i try to change that id number directly from the URL it directs me to another user's profile while i am not supposed to have permission for that .
Is there any solution ?

Answer (score 0):

A [route guard](https://angular.io/guide/router#preventing-unauthorized-access) can be used for this.

Answer (score 0):

use route guard and compare logged in user id with route parameter.
I have added below sample code for Authguard.

```js
@Injectable()
export class AuthGuardService implements CanActivate {
 
    constructor(private _router:Router ) {
    }
 
    canActivate(route: ActivatedRouteSnapshot,
                state: RouterStateSnapshot): boolean {
 
        //check some condition  
        if (someCondition)  {
            alert('You are not allowed to view this page');
            //redirect to login/home page etc
            //return false to cancel the navigation
            return false;
        } 
        return true;
    }
 
}
```